# Macro script to lock and unlock cells according to values in column A

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am new to macros and I right this macro to lock and unlock specific cells according to values from others:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    If [$A1] = "Yes" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("")
        [$E:$E].locked = True
        [$F:$F].locked = True
        [$N:$N].locked = True
        [$O:$O].locked = True
        [$P:$P].locked = True
        [$X:$X].locked = True
        [$Y:$Y].locked = True
        [$Z:$Z].locked = True
        [$AA:$AA].locked = True
        [$AB:$AB].locked = True
        [$AC:$AC].locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect ("")
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("PASSWORD")
        [$E:$E].locked = False
        [$F:$F].locked = False
        [$N:$N].locked = False
        [$O:$O].locked = False
        [$P:$P].locked = False
        [$X:$X].locked = False
        [$Y:$Y].locked = False
        [$Z:$Z].locked = False
        [$AA:$AA].locked = False
        [$AB:$AB].locked = False
        [$AC:$AC].locked = False

        ActiveSheet.Protect ("")
    End If
    If [$A1] = "No" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("")
        [$B:$B].locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect ("")
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("")
        [$B:$B].locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect ("")
    End If
End Sub
```

By `$A1` I mean to run the macro on all cells in column A and lock range of columns.

I don't know how to run and test and see if there any errors.

EDIT: i tried this and still can't test it or see how to work with it

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    If range("A1") = "Yes" Then
        range("B1:B4").locked = True
    ElseIf range("A1") = "No" Then
        range("B1:B4").locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the routine only makes sense if the cell that has changed is A1 - we should ignore this for any other cell.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Dim LockCells As Boolean
        LockCells = (UCase(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")) = "YES")
        Dim ColsToLock
        ColsToLock = Split("E,F,N,O,P,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC", ",")
        Dim r As Range
        Dim x As Integer
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""
        For x = 0 To UBound(ColsToLock) - 1
            Set r = ActiveSheet.Columns(ColsToLock(x) & ":" & ColsToLock(x))
            r.Locked = LockCells
        Next x
        ActiveSheet.Protect ""


    End If
    End Sub
```

Secondly don't forget to unprotect all cells before you start